# Trouble with line iteration using while or for

Tags: perl, shell, split, find

I am trying to process each line in a file through a perl script instead of sending the entire file to the perl script, sending so much data to memory at once.

In a shell script, I began what I thought to be line iteration as follows:

```
while read line
do
  perl script.pl --script=options "$line"
done < input
```

When I do this, how do I save the data to an output file >> output?

```
while read line
do
  perl script.pl --script=options "$line"
done < input
>> output
```

If it takes less memory to split the file, then I also had trouble with the for statement

```
for file in /dev/*
   do 
       split -l 1000 $file prefix
done < input
## Where do I save the output?

for file in /dev/out/*
   do 
      perl script.pl --script=options
```

etc...

Which is the most memory-efficient way to

Comment: Sending the entire file to the perl script is almost certainly the most effective way to do this assuming the perl script doesn't suck the entire input into memory at the start. Anything else trades much more heavily on new processes/etc. than is likely to be saved in runtime memory I would think.

Comment: My perl script does send the entire file to memory.

Comment: you're swapping a desire for memory efficiency with a dead-certain super-high use of CPU. restarting perl to process one line of data, or even 1000 lines of data at a time. And hey, `for file in /dev/*` ? Are  you sure?! That's mostly `ttys` etc, not text. You'll need to give us more info about the nature of your problem and why you're approaching it this way. As is, it seems err, well, non-optimal? :-) .... Good luck.

Comment: This is almost certainly a terrible idea. How many lines are we talking about here?

Comment: And you just need to process the file line-by-line?

Comment: My goal is to process it taking less memory. So, I thought 'split' would have been a good idea. Another programmer suggested line iteration, but I don't understand how to do it, where I use a while statement to count each line. On the 100th or so line, process that batch through the perl script and >> to the output file. So, in not sure which way is the best way.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your perl script to operate line-by-line or on ranges of lines at a time instead of loading it all into memory. Clearly it can operate in that mode or this entire idea wouldn't work.

Comment: This is absolutely a terrible, terrible idea.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed my issue with:

```
  split -l 100000 input /dev/shm/split/split.input.txt.
  find /dev/shm/split/ -type f -name '*.txt.* -exec perl script.pl --script=options {} + > output
```

This made my script process the files faster.

Answer (score 4):

also you can process your very big file line by line within perl script without loading the entire file in memory. for that you just need to enclose the text of your current perl script (that i hope doen't read the file in memory any more :) ) with while loop. for example:

```
my $line;
while ($line = <>) {
    // your script text here, refering to $line variable instead of param variable
}
```

and in this perl script you can also write results to output file. say, if result is stored in variable $res, you can do it this way:

```
open (my $fh, ">>", "out") or die "ERROR: $!"; # opening a file descriptor
my $line;
while ($line = <>) {
    // your script text here, refering to $line variable instead of param variable
    print $fh $res, "\n"; # writing to file descriptor
}
close $fh; # closing file descriptor
```

Comment: Did you mean `..., ">>", "out")` ?

Comment: You should write it as `while ( my $line = <> ){...}`. You should also check the return value of `close` ( or add a `use autodie` and remove the `open` check )

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while read line
do
  perl script.pl --script=options "$line" >> "out"
done < input
```

"out" is a name of your output file.

Comment: Up this one. Bash uses kernel buffer which only reads certain amount of lines into memory instead of full file using pure Perl

Comment: You don't have to read the entire file into memory in Perl, either.

Comment: The >> out seems to finally  get output. The problem now is that errors state "Cannot open file: ..." The filepath is correct. I tried chmod 777 on the input file. Any idea why that error would occur?

Comment: @envisisoft  Did you use exactly my script (4 lines), or a modified version? For example did you use it as a single shell line of code?

Comment: I used your lines, not a single line of code.  Is yours meant for bash or sh?